# Replace datefields in a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to replace all date fields with, for example, "hello".

This Word VBA code replaces all the fields in the header and footer of the document. I only want to replaces the date fields.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim oField As Field
    Dim oSection As Section
    Dim oHeader As HeaderFooter
    Dim oFooter As HeaderFooter
    
    For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    
        For Each oHeader In oSection.Headers
            If oHeader.Exists Then
                For Each oField In oHeader.Range.Fields
                    
                    If oField = wdFieldDate Then
                        oField.Result.Text = "hello"
                        oField.Unlink
                    Else
                    End If
                    
                Next oField
            End If
        Next oHeader
    
        For Each oFooter In oSection.Footers
            If oFooter.Exists = True Then
                 For Each oField In oFooter.Range.Fields
                     
                     If IsDate(oField) = True Then
                        oField.Result.Text = "hello"
                        oField.Unlink
                    Else
                    End If
                    
                Next oField
            End If
        Next oFooter
    
    Next oSection
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [cross-post](https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/msoffice/forum/all/word-macro-search-for-date-fields-and-replace/ad578c92-e1ce-4258-903f-552dfae2a843), you specified that you wanted DATE and TIME fields.

```
Sub DateFieldsReplace()
    ' Replace any date fields in active document
    ' Charles Kenyon  2020-09-09

    ' https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/msoffice/forum/all/word-macro-search-for-date-fields-and-replace/ad578c92-e1ce-4258-903f-552dfae2a843
    ' =====================================================
    ' DECLARE VARIABLES AND CONSTANTS
    Dim oField As Field, bErrMark As Boolean, strPrompt As String, bFieldCodeHidden As Boolean
    Dim oStory As Range
    Const strREPLACETEXT = "Hello" ' Change to suit
        '
    ' =====================================================
    ' TURN OFF SCREEN UPDATING
    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo OOPS
    Let bFieldCodeHidden = ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes ' get current setting for field code display
    Let ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
    '
    ' =====================================================
    ' FIND AND REPLACE DATE FIELDS
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        With oStory.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "^d Date"
            .Replacement.Text = strREPLACETEXT
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Text = "^d Time"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next oStory
    '
    Let strPrompt = "All Date fields replaced with " & strREPLACETEXT
    GoTo ResumeMacro
    ' =====================================================
    ' ERROR HANDLER
OOPS:
    Let strPrompt = "Sorry. There was a problem with the macro DateFieldsReplace."
    '
ResumeMacro:
    '
    ' =====================================================
    ' RETURN SCREEN UPDATING AND FINISH
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenRefresh
    Set oField = Nothing

    Set oStory = Nothing
    Let ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = bFieldCodeHidden
    On Error GoTo -1
    
    MsgBox strPrompt
    '
End Sub
```

A document with this code can be found at [this temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qadyfyxb7rxg06j/backup%20of%20deleteme%20date%20field%20replacer.wbk?dl=0).

For cross-posting etiquette, please please read: [A Message to Forum Cross-Posters](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184)

Comment: Cross-posting etiquette is to avoid it if you can and if you cannot, in each post put a link to all other posts with the same question. Many of these question and answer forums are "staffed" by knowledgeable volunteers. It is only fair to those volunteers to minimize duplication of effort.

Answer (score 0):

`If oField = wdFieldDate Then` doesn't compile because you haven't specified which property of the field you want to check. Your code should be as below

```
Sub test()
   Dim oField As Field
   Dim oSection As Section
   Dim oHeader As HeaderFooter
   Dim oFooter As HeaderFooter

   For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
      For Each oHeader In oSection.Headers
         If oHeader.Exists Then
            For Each oField In oHeader.Range.Fields
               'check the field type
               If oField.Type = wdFieldDate Then
                  oField.Result.Text = "hello"
                  oField.Unlink
               Else
               End If
            Next oField
         End If
      Next oHeader

      For Each oFooter In oSection.Footers
         If oFooter.Exists = True Then
            For Each oField In oFooter.Range.Fields
               If oField.Type = wdFieldDate Then
                  oField.Result.Text = "hello"
                  oField.Unlink
               Else
               End If
            Next oField
         End If
      Next oFooter
   Next oSection
End Sub
```